# Splitting csv file into multiple files with 2 columns in each file

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to split a file (testfile.csv) that contains the following:

```
1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9  
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h  
q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i  
a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k  
z,x,c,v,b,n,m,z
```

into a file

```
1,2  
a,b  
q,w  
a,s  
z,x
```

and another file

```
4,5    
c,d    
e,r    
d,f    
c,v
```

but I cannot seem to do that in awk using an iterative solution.

```
awk -F, '{print $1, $2}'  
awk -F, '{print $3, $4}'
```

does it for me but I would like a looping solution.

I tried

```
awk -F, '{ for (i=1;i< NF;i+=2) print $i, $(i+1) }' testfile.csv
```

but it gives me a single column. It appears that I am iterating over the first row and then moving onto the second row skipping every other element of that specific row.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `cut`:

```
$ cut -d, -f1,2 file > file_1
$ cut -d, -f3,4 file > file_2
```

If you are going to use `awk` be sure to set the `OFS` so that the columns remain a CSV file:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
       {print $1,$2 >"f1"; print $3,$4 > "f2"}' file

$ cat f1
1,2
a,b
q,w
a,s
z,x
$cat f2 
4,5
c,d
e,r
d,f
c,v
```

---

*Is there a quick and dirty way of renaming the resulting files with the first row and first column (like first file would be 1.csv, second file would be 4.csv*:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     FNR==1 {n1=$1 ".csv"; n2=$3 ".csv"}
     {print $1,$2 >n1; print $3,$4 > n2}' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a quick and dirty way of renaming the resulting files with the first row and first column (like first file would be 1.csv, second file would be 4.csv?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. This works very well with 4 columns. Is there a more 'efficient' way for say 100 columns and I want to extract 1+2, then 3+4 then 5+6 until 97+98 and finally 99,100? I have upvoted your answer since it is very neat.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
awk -F "," '{ for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) print $i "," $(i+1)  > "tmp_" i}' $1  
  
for filename in tmp_*; do  
 variable=`awk -F, 'FNR==1 {print $1}' $filename`  
 tail -n +2 $filename > $variable.csv  
 rm $filename  
done    is my ugly solution altogether

Comment: When you say *'efficient' way for say 100 columns?* You will need to define that. Efficient to write? Read? Execute? Easy to select any random group of columns? *efficient* is in the eye of the beholder...

Comment: Edited for clarity. (Is there a more 'efficient' way for say 100 columns and I want to extract 1+2, then 3+4 then 5+6 until 97+98 and finally 99,100?)

Comment: Great summarize, second `cut` has little error though, should be `-f3,4`.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F, '{ for (i=1; i < NF; i+=2) print $i, $(i+1) > i ".csv"}' tes.csv
```

works for me. I was trying to get the output in bash which was all jumbled up.

Comment: Can someone please tell me why the stdout is all messed up?

Comment: Nice answer. Note that as stated, it'l work in gawk and mawk, but not in BSD awk (including macOS).  My take variation on this would be: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) print $i, $(i+1) > (i ".csv")}' input.csv`. This sets the output delimiter, but also puts the filename declaration into brackets, which BSD awk *does* understand (and the others have no problem with).

Comment: While not 100% needed here, to remove any possible ambiguity, it is best practice to put the redirection between brackets: `print $i, $(i+1) > ( i ".csv")`. Imagine the following awk : `echo "foo bar" | awk '{print $1 > $2}'`. do you want to print `1` or do you want to print the word `foo` in the file `bar`?

Comment: You may need to close() the output files as you go, otherwise you'll get a "too many open files" error if you have more than about 20 output files and you aren't using GNU awk.

Answer (score 1):

It's do-able in bash, but it will be **much** slower than awk:

```
f=testfile.csv
IFS=, read -ra first < <(head -1 "$f")
for ((i = 0; i < (${#first[@]} + 1) / 2; i++)); do
    slice_file="${f%.csv}$((i+1)).csv"
    cut -d, -f"$((2 * i + 1))-$((2 * (i + 1)))" "$f" > "$slice_file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

with sed:

sed -r ' 
h 
s/(.,.),.*/\1/w file1.txt 

g 

s/.,.,(.,.),.*/\1/w file2.txt' file.txt